# Simple Java Array Newbie

Tags: java, bluej

I trying to teach myself Java and have started looking through the BlueJ examples.

In the case of a Surgery system I need to add patients and their addresses to an array and then have the ability to add patients and then list patients.

The example uses Vectors and hard codes adding names to the vector but i'd like to use an Array and allow the user to add names and addresses to the array.

can anyone offer some guidance?

I have the following but not sure where to go from here.

```
public class Patient
{
    public String name;
    public String address;

   public Patient(String n, String a) {
      name = n;
      address = a;
   }


}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should start with the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html). I'd recommend starting at the beginning, but there's a section on [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) as well.

Comment: It is worth noting that using a `Vector` here is probably the right thing to do. In Java (as in many languages) it is rather verbose to _grow_ an array (to allow more elements to be added to it) since array dimensions are fixed. `Vector`s (and other Java standard collection classes, such as `List`s and `Set`s) are more effective here.

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning that if you've got examples that use the `Vector` class they're in all likelihood very outdated - `ArrayList` has all but replaced it for many years now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to give you the exact answer as this looks very much like homework, but here's a sample implementation of a Hotel using arrays. Go through it and try to make sense of it; if you do, you'll be able to do the Patient problem on your own.

```
import java.util.*;

class Customer
{
    private String name;
    private int room;

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setRoom(int room)
    {
        this.room=room;
    }

    public int getRoom()
    {
        return this.room;
    }
}

class Hotel
{
    public static void initialize(Customer RoomList[])
    {
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
        {
            RoomList[i]=new Customer();
            RoomList[i].setName("EMPTY");
            RoomList[i].setRoom(i+1);
        }
    }

    public static void viewList(Customer RoomList[])
    {
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
        {
            if(RoomList[i].getName()=="EMPTY")
                System.out.println("Room number "+RoomList[i].getRoom()+" is vacant.");
            else
                System.out.println("Room number "+RoomList[i].getRoom()+" is ocupied by "+RoomList[i].getName()+".");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static boolean addCustomer(Customer RoomList[], String name)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
            if(RoomList[i].getName().equals("EMPTY"))
            {
                RoomList[i].setName(name);
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

    public static void showEmptyRooms(Customer RoomList[])
    {
        System.out.println("Available rooms are:");
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
            if(RoomList[i].getName()=="EMPTY")
                System.out.println(RoomList[i].getRoom());
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static boolean deleteCustomer(Customer RoomList[], String name)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
            if(RoomList[i].getName().equals(name))
            {
                RoomList[i].setName("EMPTY");
                System.out.println("Deletion successful.\n");
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

    public static int getIndex(Customer RoomList[], String name)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
            if(RoomList[i].getName().equals(name))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int numOfCustomers=10;
        Customer[] RoomList = new Customer[numOfCustomers];
        String name;
        initialize(RoomList);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option=0;

        do
        {
            System.out.println("        Hotel Booking Options");
            System.out.println("=====================================");
            System.out.println("1: To View all rooms");
            System.out.println("2: To Add customer to a room");
            System.out.println("3: To Display empty rooms");
            System.out.println("4: To Delete customer from a room");
            System.out.println("5: Find room from customer name");
            System.out.println("0: Exit");

            System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
            option = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println();

            switch(option)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    viewList(RoomList);
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    System.out.print("Customer's name: ");
                    name=input.next();
                    System.out.println();
                    if(!addCustomer(RoomList, name))
                        System.out.println("No rooms available!");
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    showEmptyRooms(RoomList);
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    System.out.print("Customer's name: ");
                    name=input.next();
                    System.out.println();
                    deleteCustomer(RoomList, name);
                    break;
                }
                case 5:
                {
                    System.out.print("Customer's name: ");
                    name=input.next();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Customer's room: "+RoomList[getIndex(RoomList, name)].getRoom()+"\n");
                    break;
                }
                case 0:
                {
                    System.out.println("\nThank you!\n");
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid option!\n");
                    break;
                }
            }


        }while(option!=0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roney, it isn't homework, It's just sometimes difficult to grasp what a book is getting at. I think what I am struggling more with is adding a 2 different fields to an array and then returning the values from one of the fields. I'll work through your example and try and apply some of it to what I'm trying. It's much appreciated.

Comment: @user1295053: My mistake. :) Anyway, this code should clear those doubts, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

This kind of information is quite well documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

In your case, it seems like you want to create an array of type `Patient`

The syntax for creating an array that can hold ten patients is:

```
Patient[] patients = new Patients[10];
```

And after you read the documentation, you'll be able to use the syntax I've provided to get the desired functionality :)